# Importing esri shapefile with features into MySQL with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, shapefile, esri

I have an ESRI shapefile (zip files) that includes Vermont voting precincts and vote results in 2016. I use phpmyadmin "import" functionality to import the file into MySQL. When done, a new table is created that includes only 1 column called SPATIAL. So it seems only the polygons are imported and none of the features (vote results) are in the MySQL table.

Am I missing something or is it how it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after much research:
You need to have the dbase extension enabled on your PHP for the import to work on the attributes as well.

Comment: How enable dbase extension?